# Rails + AMCharts with vertical legend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amcharts

I followed http://railsontherun.com/2007/10/04/sexy-charts-in-less-than-5-minutes/ to get regular line charts working on my rails app. Now I'm trying to use http://www.amcharts.com/stock/vertical-legend/ but the I seem to be running into issues. Can anyone tell by looking at the tutorial what needs to change to make it work?

Thanks,
Elliot

Comment: What sort of issues are you having? Rails or Amcharts? Can you post some error output?

Comment: Turns out it needed a CSV file, not XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it needed a CSV file, not XML